# request.get() - if url not found

Tags: node.js, request

So I want to end the request if the user tries to fetch a url which does not work.

This works:

```
var remote = "https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/testfolder/OUTOFAREA.mp3";  

    var streama = request.get(remote);
```

however lets say the following mp3 does not exisit

> https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/testfolder/playme.mp3

When the `request.get('https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/testfolder/playme.mp3');` tries and fetch the file it will return a 404 error. What I want to do is file not found I want to run `res.end();`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the context for this code so we can see more of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write like ### request('endpoint url goes here',  { json: true },  (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) { // keep your business logic here}
})   ######

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't know about this Cloud Storage but even the link isn't accessible so I recommend you check if something is wrong in this service or if you require some special keys or something else to access the content or the service. Then, check your code or use a library that can handle your requirements (if available).

If I found something, I'll let you know :)

**EDIT:** I can access to https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/testfolder/Video/30%20Second%20Timer-0yZcDeVsj_Y.f137.mp4

Comment: I know but what if the file did not exists?

Comment: You have to validate the response codes (like 404). You can use Axios library to make it work.

Comment: This is the axios' github page: https://github.com/axios/axios

There is everything you need and is very well documented in case you need to investigate on other sites or videos. Axios is easy to use

Comment: Also if you are using express.js you have to keep in mind what you really want to do with the file since it depends a lot in some cases as headers to show in the browser like the "default player"

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
app.get("*",(req,res)=> {
    res.end()
});
```

and insert it just before your 404 handler however, I would challenge why that ever might be a good idea. If it's literally so you scan skip checking the return code I really advice you to think twice if thats something you wanna be doing atleast do:

```
app.get("*",(req,res)=> {
    res.status(404)
    res.end()
});
```